# How do I form planes into existing object?

Tags: modeling, texturing, modifiers

So, I want to make a cave in Blender.
I used a circle as a starting point, extruded it, used some subdivision, sculpting, yadda yadda, standard stuff.
But I'm not happy with the way textures are portrayed on the finalized cave.
It shouldn't be one texture, mapped on the thing, the texture isn't made for that. The texture should be on the object multiple times.
So my idea was to make a plane with the texture, multiply that plane(using array modifiers, make the single planes smaller for detail) and somehow apply that to the cave object.
How do I do that? With a shrinkwrap? How it reads, that should be the way to go, but im not shure I understand it correctly.
I added the blendfile to [drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gFSUc_-pdlu96G7gEPPFBiiu7_VAEKLI)

Comment: Is there a reason you do not just apply the texture as a UV map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it with a procedural texture, but if you absolutely want to use an image texture, I see at least two ways to do it, tell me if it answers.

- First, as Keavon says, you could **UVmap** your object with a texture.
- Prepare your texture, it needs to be tileable.
- As your object is already made, create a seam along an edge, and unwrap.

[image]

- Your object is not orthogonal, so it will be displayed as a twisted mesh in the *UV/Image Editor*. It won't allow the image texture to be repeated seamlessly, so you need to orthogonalize your UV. To do that you need to use an addon like [UV Squares](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/UV/Uv_Squares/). Once installed, open the T panel on the left of the *UV/Image Editor* window > Misc, press *To Square Grid*. Rescale the UV on the Y axis and on all axis, move it...

[image]

- Don't forget to plug the *Image Texture* node into a Diffuse in the Shader Editor. Now your uvmap is orthogonal and the image texture will repeat seamlessly. Advantage of this method: you need only one picture and it doesn't need to be big as it is repeated. Small problem with this method: the texture may be a bit distorted on some parts.

[image]

- The second method would be to **paint** the texture on your whole object.
- Prepare a second material, create a second UV map for this one, this time unwrap with the *Smart UV Project* mode. Create a new (black) image in the *UV/Image Editor* with the "+" button. This image needs to be large enough because it will have to cover the whole object, so you need to decide, depending on your final goal. Plug the *Image Texture* node in the *Diffuse*, and load this new image. Put an *Input* > *UV Map* node before if you've created a second UV map.

[image]

- In the *3D View* switch to *Texture Paint* mode. In the *T* panel > *Tools* > *Texture*, create a new texture, and in the *Properties* panel > *Texture*, choose *Brush - Texture* to determine what texture you will use for your brush, choose your cave wall texture (doesn't need to be tileable this time).

[image]

- On the *T* panel > *Tools* > *Texture* > *Brush Mapping*, choose *Stencil*. It will overlay the texture image on the *3D View* and allow you to project it on your object. To be complete about stencil, how to change its position [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-change-stencil-position/577489).

[image]

- You should be able to paint your object, and the painting will appear on the new image you've created in the *UV/Image Editor*. Advantage of this method: You can apply the texture as you want on the object, it may look more natural. Disavantage: As it is not a repeated pattern you need a big image that covers all your object.

[image]

With both the 2 methods, to make everything more realistic you need to complicate a bit your nodes organisation: add glossiness and bump maps, etc...

Comment: Thanks for that.  Dindn't know about the Seam thing.  That should make it possible. Yeah, it has to be this specific texture, its for a fan project for Breath of the wild.  I'm never gonna be able to actually capture the actual style of that game, but at least I can use it's textures. I probably have to work on that model anyway, at its current state unwrapping it just melts the RAM. But at least I now know what to do after that.